# Does this forum have a feature using which we can follow questions/ answers of particular members?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is there (or can there be) an option of following the activity (questions and answers posted) of particular forum members? It may be helpful in educating oneself with the thoughts of particular members who we feel are likeminded or whose thoughts are to our liking. It will also be helpful to new members (like me) for tracking and learning from the past activity of these members.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Consider an answer [like this one](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/a/11342/254) for example.

The user name of the author of that answer ("Andrei Volkov") is immediately below the answer.

That user name is a hyperlink: if you click on it you will see that user's user profile, where you can choose to see [their profile](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrei-volkov?tab=profile) or [their activity](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrei-volkov?tab=topactivity).

There are links on the Activity page from which you can list all their questions, [all their answers](https://buddhism.stackexchange.com/users/43/andrei-volkov?tab=answers), etc.

Comment: That works for the past activity log. But how about getting alerts on latest activity of particular users?

Comment: I don't know of any "alerts" of any sort ... except perhaps an RSS feed. Subscribing to RSS and doing a filter-by-user (if that's possible) might let you implement what you're asking for (if you're a software developer who can write an RSS filter). I don't know about RSS but there are [questions tagged 'rss'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rss) on the main (not Buddhism-specific) meta-site. I haven't read them but [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242989/139866) asks for that feture "User Answers") which implies the feature doesn't exist.

Comment: I guess (don't know) that if you're a software developer with time to spare, you might be able to write a filter to filter an RSS feed after you receive it and before you use it to generate alerts, i.e.: a) subscribe to RSS of the site; b) scan it to look for the user you're interested in; c) alert if found.

Comment: Alternatively, the "latest activity" eventually becomes "the past activity"; so you could e.g. scan the user's Activity from their profile occasionally, to find their latest past activity.

Comment: [here](http://buddhism.stackexchange.com/feeds/user/43) is the link to andrei's feed -- you can load it into any RSS reader, perhaps one that can send alerts upon new content. Probably just changing the user number (in his case, 43) to the user you want to follow is enough

Comment: @KaKo Please see Thiago's comment posted above this one.

Comment: I'm not best with softwares, but I'll try and execute what you have suggested by reading up on the net when I get some time.